# How to fix file_get_contents warning

Tags: php, google-checkout

I am using following code in Google checkout gateway handler, but when I test it, it shows below warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/XXXXXXXXXXX) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required in /sample.php on line 116

My line 116 looks like below:

```
//some more code//
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
echo file_get_contents($_googleUrl, false, $ctx);
exit;
```

Can somebody help me here.

Comment: Don't like to suggest that, but you might be better of with the cURL functions. They set that automatically for POST requests. Else adding headers is simpler than with the streams API.

Comment: Yup. Just use cURL library API. You will save some hassle setting up HTTPS context. (cURL needs some setup for https too, but it's at least better documented it seems.)

Answer (score 0):

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Code411)

> **411 Length Required**
>
> The server refuses to accept the request without a defined
>   Content-Length. The client may repeat the request if it adds a valid
>   Content-Length header field containing the length of the entity body
>   in the request message.

This could mean that you are either not sending or sending an incorrect `Content-Length` header in your request. Without knowing the contents of your `$params` array it is difficult to debug this. So you will either need to get rid of the `Content-Length` header if you are sending an incorrect one and let PHP handle it automatically (assuming PHP will do this) or if you are not currently sending it, send a correct one. As others have suggested, cURL may be a more viable option for doing this.

Also, doing a bit more research shows that some servers (mis)behave this way when you use POST, but do not provide any POST variables. You can therefore solve this in one of two ways if this is the case.

1. Use GET instead of POST (preferred).
2. If you cannot use GET, provide some dummy POST variables if you are not sending any.

Comment: I am not getting your clue here, can you please elaborate here?

Comment: Try posting the output of `var_dump($params);`